# Проблема в скрипте Javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Всем привет. Задача такая, что нужно показать модальное окно пользователю, который зашел на сайт первый раз. Так вот, реализацию модального окна сделал, проблем нет. Логика при проверке, первый ли раз вошел на сайт?

```
<script>  
(function($) {  
$(function() {

  // Проверим, есть ли запись в куках о посещении посетителя  
  // Если запись есть - ничего не делаем  
  if (!$.cookie('was')) {

    // Покажем всплывающее окно  
    $('#myModal').reveal({

            })

  }

  // Запомним в куках, что посетитель к нам уже заходил  
  $.cookie('was', true, {  
    expires: 365,  
    path: '/'  
  });

})  
})(jQuery)

        </script>
```

Почему-то не работает, выдает ошибку на строчке `"if (!$.cookie('was')) { " - undefined is not function`.

Ссылка на сайт [тут](http://new.marinatravelkz.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на странице не загружен нужный плагин ([jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)).